# Can we hook the screen buffer and change the color at some coordinates?

Tags: windows, winapi, colors, screen, hook

I would like to create a color mapper which will find any matched colors on the screen and render the mapped colors instead. This would be useful for some color blinds (such as they cannot see red colors so all red pixels should be mapped to some blue ones).

I know about the gdi32 functions `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` but I'm fairly sure that the performance will be bad. Technically you have to loop through all screen coordinates, get pixel, check it and set pixel. Also when we do that loop is  important to improve the performance. But any way that would be fairly intensive.

It would be ideal if we could some how hook into the rendering process of the OS (such as the screen buffer, ...) to check and modify the pixel right there. That's very similar to how `WPF` supports a layer allowing us to inject some pixel shader (via `Effect` property).

I would like to get some suggestions from you on how this could be done. It would be enough if there are some Win API function names suggested because I've already known how to hook with `EasyHook`.
I'm sure this is possible but may be hard to do. Any suggestion would be appreciated.